# How to Customize Log File Name and Location in Microsoft Enterprise Library 2.0?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, enterprise-library

I am using .net 2.0 and Microsoft Enterprise Library 2.0. How can I customize the log file name and location. I want to create a log file in my app location and current date as file name. I tried fileName="foo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to incorporate the date into the file name you will have to use programmatic configuration.  See [Programatic Configuraton - Enterprise Library (v2.0) Logging Block](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/02/16/69784.aspx) for an example targeting version 2.0 (luckily enough).

If this is a rolling date (change the date every day for example) then you will have to incorporate some reconfiguration (to change the file name) or to create a custom  trace listener.

Comment: Got it. your link helped me. I found customized file name in that blog loops. Thanks.